# Cache running average results inside postgres for faster queries

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres of 10000 records initially which keeps growing. I am writing a query to take the average of the last 1000 rows. As for example

The table A consists of a column id which I am calculating the average as

```
SELECT avg(id) FROM
   (SELECT id FROM A ORDER BY index DESC LIMIT 1000) AS num;
```

The thing is there are a lot of repetitions involved since every time I query I am going over the older rows in the table. Is there a way to cache the running average of the last 1000 rows through the query itself such that repetitions are avoided?

I tried caching the results through the driver program in memory but could not find a way to do it through Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to cache query results on the database is a *materialized view*:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myaverage AS
SELECT avg(id) AS average FROM
   (SELECT id FROM A ORDER BY index DESC LIMIT 1000) AS num;
```

That will execute the query once and store the result. You have to `REFRESH` the materialized view regularly, so that the data don't get too stale.